# Download file from url in docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a python application that uses Gensim word2vec. When I compose docker images using the following docker file, it downloads `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` but when running the application using `docker-compose up --build`, I get an error that the file doesn't exists.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/models/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
```

When I check my container, I can't find the file. What am I missing here?

```
#Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir -p /text_features \
  && mkdir -p /text_features/data/models

COPY ./requirements.txt ./text_features

WORKDIR /text_features

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
   && pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

ADD https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz /text_features/data/models/

COPY . ./text_features

EXPOSE 5010

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "5010"]
```

This is also my docker-compose.yml file.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: web_textfeatures
    container_name: web_textfeatures
    ports:
      - "5010:5000"
    command: python3 manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/text_features
```

Comment: You're bind-mounting the current directory on the host over the directory in the image that has the downloaded file.  Delete the `volumes:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file and it should work again.  (The `container_name:` and `command:` aren't necessary either; the `ports:` don't match what you have specified in the `Dockerfile`, the second port should be 5010.)

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze. I removed those lines you suggested from `docker-compose.yml`. now I get this error `python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: If you get a debugging shell in your image (`docker-compose run web bash`) do you see the `manage.py` script?  (I think it is probably one level deeper in your filesystem hierarchy than you intend.)

Comment: correct. since I am doing `COPY . ./text_features` in /text_features, everything is one level deeper. thanks